# Back and forth app redirection using Apple shortcuts

Tags: ios, ios-shortcut

So, upon opening app A, I've successfully made it so that it opens up app B immediately. However, I want the ability to close out of app B and return to app A without the shortcut being triggered again, where I am sent back to app B. Preferably I'd want the shortcut to not be triggered for the next ten minutes.

Does anyone have any advice on how to accomplish this?

I've been playing around with setting variables, if statements, "wait", and stopping the shortcut, but nothing's worked. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!